Boot a BIOS partition from UEFI
I would like to boot a BIOS partition from UEFI grub. How would I do this?
I've already tried chainloader, but it only chainloads other UEFI systems.

@Ramhound why not?  I confess UEFI vs Legacy BIOS partitioning is not my strong point but surely once you are at the stage where you are in Grub you can then get grub to load the kernel from any device it can see - and there is no reason it would not be able to see a BIOS/MBR partition?

@Ramhound - wouldn't this be case 3 listed at https://superuser.com/questions/1165557/how-grub2-works-on-a-mbr-partitioned-disk-and-gpt-partitioned-disk ?

This question is similar to: How grub2 works on a MBR partitioned disk and GPT partitioned disk?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

What OS are you trying to boot, because as of 2017, all Linux and BSD OSes support EFI boot (Windows has supported it since Win 7)?

@JW0914 All mainstream Linux distros supported it since late 2012.

This is an interesting question, but it lacks a lot of detail. Also I'd wager that you don't really want to know if it's possible, but rather, how to successfully boot.... "Is it possible" questions are often closed because the real answer to those is either yes or no, and that isn't actually all that helpful, and people get upset when they receive the answer they asked for but it wasn't the answer they actually wanted. I recommend that you use the EDIT button and clarify your question. Tell us what you've tried, with specific steps, tell us about your computer (or computers).

I am confused by what you mean by "boot a BIOS partition from UEFI". My literal interpretation would be for the firmware to switch from UEFI booting to BIOS booting, then load the first sector of the partition into memory and execute the code contained in the loaded sector. If correct, then the answer to your question is no.
The closest I think of, that would do what you want, would involve 2006 through 2014 Intel Apple computers. Most (if not all) of these Macs were capable of both BIOS and (U)EFI booting. GRUB2 offered an appleloader command which would cause a (U)EFI booting Mac to restart as a BIOS booting Mac. If properly configured, the first sector of the drive then would be loading into memory and executed.
If the appleloader command did not work for a given Mac, then GRUB2 could be setup to boot rEFInd. The rEFInd Boot Manager could then be configured to silently instruct the firmware to restart and BIOS boot the Mac.
This answer to the question How to get GRUB working dual boot Windows(Legacy) PopOS(UEFI) offers additional information. (In many respects, this question is a duplicate of the linked question.)
Other References

Ubuntu documentation: UEFIBooting
GNU GRUB Manual 2.12: Various loader commands


So, there's nothing a UEFI bootloader could do to emulate BIOS code without getting the firmware involved? Why not, though?

You are asking an UEFI bootloader to place into memory code that would then try to complete a BIOS boot. This code would expect to interact with a BIOS implemented in the firmware. This would be a problem, because the firmware would be only accepting UEFI interactions.
